# Identification of what method to apply when solving general math problems?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Good day,

I have been following single variable calculus, and I have problems solving the examination questions. Simpy said, I have difficulties with identifying what method of integration and/or differentiation to apply, to reach the desired answer.

For example:

[Two examination questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gghir.png)

> 3. Determine $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\sin x\sin(2x)\,dx.$
> 4. Determine $\int \frac{x^6+1}{x^4-1}\,dx.$

I do not seek an answer to these question, more a way on how to tackle such problems, and how to identify what method to apply to solve them (substitution/partial/approximation with squeeze theorem.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For problem 1- trig identities. For problem 2- division algorithm

Comment: $$(x^6+1,x^4-1)=?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practice. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perhaps that is true, but if I start to work out a question, and do not know how to tackle the problem, how is that practice? They say you learn from your failures, but if you keep failing, it should be considered ignorance.

Comment: Integration is a form of art, in a way. If you keep failing with your practice problems, then you need to find better practice problems, adapted to your current skill level. There are books out there with literally thousands of exercises, going from the trivial-for-everybody to the impossible-for-all-but-a-few. When I was a student I had trouble with series, and I found a book by several russian authors which had some 900 problems about series. I started from the beginning and went on for quite some time until a point at which I had learned how to deal with series. Do that.

Comment: I suppose you are right then, I shall practice more to get a feeling for it. Thank you for your reply.